# Equally spaced images in a flexbox

Tags: html, css

I am using a flexbox container that is using a row layout that wraps. Each of the items is exactly the same size (150x267 pixels). I have added a margin of 10px to each of the items to provide some space.

Flexbox does a great job of laying out the items but I am trying to get a layout so that whatever the viewport width, the spacing between each of the items is the same. Sometimes this occurs but at a width of about 1400px, there is noticeably a much larger gap between the images than the 10px margin on each end of the row.

My CSS is

```
div#imgcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 0;
}
div#imgcontainer img {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

You can see an example of the layout at [3-dot-timb-photos.appspot.com](http://3-dot-timb-photos.appspot.com/)

Comment: have you tried % instead px ?

Comment: I can't do that on the images (they need to remain the same size) but that could help with the margin. Thanks.

Comment: I was referring to the margin ;)